# Using SQL, how to calculate the value at 70%?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, percentage

Given a table of student with column name and grade, how to calculate the grade at 70% order by grade desc?

Comment: sample data and expected result would be helpful

Comment: What is your attempt?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example: (1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. (2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. (3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above. (4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;). All within the question, no images.